# how to record mouse movements in python?

Tags: python, pygame

I've been using pygame to track mouse movements and I was wondering if there was a a way to somehow record them so I can playback the mouse positions. I'm trying to develop a kind of machine learning program. This is what I have so far:

```
import pygame
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time



servoPIN = 17
servoPIN2 = 27
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(servoPIN, GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.setup(servoPIN2, GPIO.OUT)

p = GPIO.PWM(servoPIN, 50) # GPIO 17 for PWM with 50Hz
r = GPIO.PWM(servoPIN2, 50)
p.start(5.5)
r.start(5.5)



running = True
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1200, 1200))
while running:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        (x,y) = event.pos
        print (x,y)
        d = float(x/100)
        f = float(y/100)
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(d)
        r.ChangeDutyCycle(f)
```

Comment: Not a `machine-learning` or `raspberry-pi3` question - please do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 0):

You can store the (x,y) positions in a file. Say. `mouseMovements.txt`

This file can be read by the library `pyautogui` and then you can play the mouse.

```
import pyautogui

ifp = open("mouseMovements.txt", "r")

for line in ifp:
    x, y = line.strip().split(",")
    pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
```

Here is the detailed doc if you need more help. https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a list of the mouse positions. Then you could loop back through them.

Instead of getting the mouse position when you move the mouse, You could get it every frame so it wouldn't constantly be moving, it would wait, if you waited in the recording.

```
Mouse_recording = []
while running:
    MouseX, MouseY = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    Mouse_recording.append((MouseX,MouseY))
    #do other stuff
```

This might be too fast and give you too many points so you could set the fps with `pygame.time.Clock()`

```
Clock = pygame.time.Clock()
while running:
    Clock.tick(60) # stops the program from running more than 60 fps
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a list. You want to store the positions which you have use as input `ChangeDutyCycle`:

```py
mouse_pos = [] 

while running:
    event = pygame.event.poll()
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        running = False

    elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
        (x,y) = event.pos
        mouse_pos.append((x, y))
        # [...]
```

For instance you can store the list to a [*csv* File](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html):

```py
with open("mouse_pos.csv", mode='w')  as csv_file:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    for pos in mouse_pos: 
        csv_writer.writerow(pos)
```

And read it back to a list:

```py
mouse_pos = []
with open("mouse_pos.csv") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        if len(row) >= 2:
            mouse_pos.append((int(row[0]), int(row[1])))
```

Later you can "replay" the positions from the list:

```py
for (x, y) in mouse_pos:  
    d = float(x/100)
    f = float(y/100)
    p.ChangeDutyCycle(d)
    r.ChangeDutyCycle(f)
```

It is even possible to set the mouse position by [`pygame.mouse.set_pos()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html#pygame.mouse.set_pos):

```py
pos_i = 0
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
running = True
while running:
    clock.tick(10)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    if pos_i < len(mouse_pos)
        (x,y) = mouse_pos[pos_i]
        pos_i += 1
        pygame.mouse.set_pos((x, y))
        d = float(x/100)
        f = float(y/100)
        p.ChangeDutyCycle(d)
        r.ChangeDutyCycle(f) 

    else:
        running = False
```